# Bit flags as input in a routine for validating

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum Property
{
    HasClaws   = 1 << 0,
    CanFly     = 1 << 1,
    EatsFish   = 1 << 2,
    Endangered = 1 << 3
};

bool isHawk(int prop)  // <-- Is the input type correct?
{
    //  If it can fly then also it is a hawk. If it has claws then also it is a hawk.
    if (prop& HasClaws || prop& CanFly)
    {
        return true;
    }

    //  If it can fly as well has claws then also it is a hawk.
    if ((prop& (HasClaws | CanFly)) == (HasClaws | CanFly))  //<-- Can this be written cleaner/simpler
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Value = " << isHawk(CanFly | HasClaws) << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Couple of my questions are inline in the above code.

In the second if condition `if ((prop& (HasClaws | CanFly)) == (HasClaws | CanFly))`, what I really wanted to check is, if it can both fly as well as has claws. Is `OR` the right operator for this or should it be `AND`? Same is the question while calling `isHawk(CanFly | HasClaws)`.

In general, can `isHawk()` as written above, be written in a simpler/cleaner way?

This is just an example code. It has nothing to do with hawks or being a hawk.

Comment: What is the first condition supposed to check?

Comment: First condition: If it can fly then also it is a hawk. If it has claws then also it is a hawk.

Comment: So why do you ever expect the second condition to become true? If it can both fly and has claws, it can fly, and thus has already been identified as a hawk?

Comment: What about animals that can fly but do not have claws, or animals that have claws but cannot fly?  Neither of those conditions describe a hawk.

Comment: Also, technically birds (especially birds of prey) have *talons*, whereas *claws* is more commonly associated with mammals and reptiles instead. So you might consider defining a `HasTalons` bit to differentiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the input type correct?

Defining `prop` as `int` is fine.  Just know that you have 28 unused bytes.  You might consider using an `unsigned char` or `unsigned short` instead to reduce the number of bits used.

> Can this be written cleaner/simpler

You could add another value to your enum to combine the `HasClaws` and `CanFly` bits under a single name:

```
enum Property
{
    HasClaws   = 1 << 0,
    CanFly     = 1 << 1,
    EatsFish   = 1 << 2,
    Endangered = 1 << 3,
    HasClawsAndCanFly = HasClaws | CanFly
};
```

```
if ((prop & HasClawsAndCanFly) == HasClawsAndCanFly)
```

> In the second if condition `if ((prop& (HasClaws | CanFly)) == (HasClaws | CanFly))`, what I really wanted to check is, if it can both fly as well as has claws. Is OR the right operator for this or should it be AND?

The `|` is correct.  The real problem is the `||` in the first `if`.  If you pass in either `HasClaws` or `CanFly` by itself, you are returning `true` when you should be returning `false` instead:

```
isHawk(HasClaws) // returns true
isHawk(CanFly) // returns true
isHawk(HasClaws | CanFly) // returns true
isHawk(HasClawsAndCanFly) // returns true
```

You need to remove the first `if` altogether:

```
bool isHawk(int prop)
{    
    if ( (prop & (HasClaws | CanFly)) == (HasClaws | CanFly))
    //if ( (prop & HasClawsAndCanFly) == HasClawsAndCanFly)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Which can then be simplified:

```
bool isHawk(int prop)
{    
    return ((prop & (HasClaws | CanFly)) == (HasClaws | CanFly));
    //return ((prop & HasClawsAndCanFly) == HasClawsAndCanFly);
}
```